# The specified type member 'SubArea' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

Getting the following error on GroupBy 2 separate fields.

I have spent the past 2 days wondering why this is not working. I know I might be missing an obvious part, please help.

```
var res = db.Properties.GroupBy(x => x.AreaName)
                      .Select(x => new PropVM
                      {
                          AreaName = x.Key,
                          SubCount =x.Count()
                          
                      }).GroupBy(x => new { sub = x.SubArea})
                      .Select(x => new PropVM
                      {
                          SubArea = x.Key.sub
                      });
            

            return View(res);
```

View

```
<h2>Groupby</h2>
<div class="row">
    @foreach(var i in Model)
    {
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p>@i.AreaName</p>
        <p>@i.SubArea</p>
    </div>
        
    }
</div>
```

Property Model Class

```
public string SubArea { get; set; }
public int AreaId { get; set; }
public string AreaName { get; set; }
```

PropVM Model Class

```
public string AreaName { get; set; }
public string SubArea { get; set; }

public string AreaSlug { get; set; }

public string SubAreaSlug { get; set; }

public int SubCount { get; set; }
```

With this Code it is working but the View is rendering in List format, instead of Side by Side. How to show view in SideBySide view?

Working Action Method:

```
 

    var res = db.Properties
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.AreaName, r.SubArea })
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.AreaName)
                .Select(g => new PropVM { AreaName = g.Key.AreaName, SubArea = g.Key.SubArea, SubCount = g.Count() });
    
                return View(res.ToList());
```

View is as follows

```
    @{
        var area = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @if (item.AreaName != area)
                {
                    <p><b>@item.AreaName</b></p>
                    area = item.AreaName;
                }
                <p>@item.SubArea  @item.SubCount</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

See the below image of how this should render on View.

[image: ListView]

Comment: How the `Properties` is defined? Add related code parts to the post, please.

Comment: Model Class info updated to the post. Please take a look. Thank you for looking at it

Comment: Why are you trying to group twice? What are you trying to do? Even if that query worked, the second `GroupBy` works on `PropVM` whose `SubArea` is empty at this point. This doesn't work though, because it's trying to group *using SQL* fields that don't exist

Comment: Are you trying to group by area and subarea? Use a single `GroupBy(x => {x.AreaName,x.SubArea})`

Comment: Yes, I want to GroupBy AreaName and SubArea. This is how it should show China
HongKong 1
Beijeing 1

India
Delhi 2 
Mumbai 1

Australia
Melbourne 1
Sydney 1

Comment: See the image updated

Comment: I did use a single GroupyBy, but and it renders AreaName multiple times which I do not want. What am I doing wrong here? Kindly suggest

Comment: Following Code works as I want it to but the View shows in a Long List format. How to make the view render side by side instead of a Long List View.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var res = db.Properties
            .GroupBy(r => new { r.AreaName, r.SubArea })
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key.AreaName)
            .Select(g => new PropVM { AreaName = g.Key.AreaName, SubArea = g.Key.SubArea , SubCount = g.Count() });

return View(res.ToList());
```

The query above is designed to maximize performance and taking into account your view data model structure. You are using all properties in the view: `AreaName`, `SubArea` and `SubCount`. In additional the data is sorted by `AreaName`. Therefore it is possible to use the following code to build the view:

```xml
@{
    var area = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            @if  (item.AreaName != area)
            {                    
                <p><b>@item.AreaName</b></p>
                area = item.AreaName;
            }                
                <p>@item.SubArea  @item.SubCount</p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What if statement to write to Print the AreaName ,please suggest

Comment: I Just tried the above code, but it is printing the AreaName many times.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, will try this

Comment: Hello @Jackdaw this works like a charm, but the view shows AreaName with their set of Sub Area one below each other. How can I show AreaName side by side with their set of SubArea below their own AreaName. See the image attached for what I am looking to achieve. Thank you again.

Comment: @RS: **When the question is answered don't change the question content to create a new question, please.** Instead of that post a new question. 
If your question is answered, please do mark it as such. Thanks. And read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)